# Is there a way to align these <TextInput> boxes (lines)?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm doing an app on React Native and am stuck trying to align these input boxes, I have tried everything as far as I'm concerned but can't manage to do it.. [The 'lines' I'm talking about, every line is an input box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsUra.png)

The numbers used on the 'top' commands are arbitrary numbers I chose because they looked right, but maybe there is a way to properly align them right

```
<Text style={{fontSize:20, color:'white', textAlign:'left', top:20, marginVertical:12,}}>Agressividade</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={{color:'white', fontSize:20,
                borderTopWidth : 0, borderLeftWidth: 0, borderRightWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth : 1,
                borderColor:'white', height:30, width:170, marginVertical:6,
                position: 'absolute', right:1, top: 20}}
                keyboardType='decimal-pad'
            />
            <Text style={{fontSize:20, color:'white', textAlign:'left', top:20, marginVertical:12,}}>Agressividade</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={{color:'white', fontSize:20,
                borderTopWidth : 0, borderLeftWidth: 0, borderRightWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth : 1,
                borderColor:'white', height:30, width:170,
                position: 'absolute', right:1, top: 78}}
                keyboardType='decimal-pad'
            />
            <Text style={{fontSize:20, color:'white', textAlign:'left', top:20, marginVertical:12,}}>Agressividade</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={{color:'white', fontSize:20,
                borderTopWidth : 0, borderLeftWidth: 0, borderRightWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth : 1,
                borderColor:'white', height:30, width:170,
                position: 'absolute', right:1, top: 126}}
                keyboardType='decimal-pad'
            />
            <Text style={{fontSize:20, color:'white', textAlign:'left', top:20, marginVertical:12,}}>Agressividade</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={{color:'white', fontSize:20,
                borderTopWidth : 0, borderLeftWidth: 0, borderRightWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth : 1,
                borderColor:'white', height:30, width:170,
                position: 'absolute', right:1, top: 178}}
                keyboardType='decimal-pad'
            />
            <Text style={{fontSize:20, color:'white', textAlign:'left', top:20, marginVertical:12,}}>Agressividade</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={{color:'white', fontSize:20,
                borderTopWidth : 0, borderLeftWidth: 0, borderRightWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth : 1,
                borderColor:'white', height:30, width:170,
                position: 'absolute', right:1, top: 229}}
                keyboardType='decimal-pad'
            />
            <Text style={{fontSize:20, color:'white', textAlign:'left', top:20, marginVertical:12,}}>Agressividade</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={{color:'white', fontSize:20,
                borderTopWidth : 0, borderLeftWidth: 0, borderRightWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth : 1,
                borderColor:'white', height:30, width:170,
                position: 'absolute', right:1, top: 281}}
                keyboardType='decimal-pad'
            />
            <Text style={{fontSize:20, color:'white', textAlign:'left', top:20, marginVertical:12,}}>Agressividade</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={{color:'white', fontSize:20,
                borderTopWidth : 0, borderLeftWidth: 0, borderRightWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth : 1,
                borderColor:'white', height:30, width:170,
                position: 'absolute', right:1, top: 331}}
                keyboardType='decimal-pad'
            />
            <Text style={{fontSize:20, color:'white', textAlign:'left', top:20, marginVertical:12,}}>Agressividade</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={{color:'white', fontSize:20,
                borderTopWidth : 0, borderLeftWidth: 0, borderRightWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth : 1,
                borderColor:'white', height:30, width:170,
                position: 'absolute', right:1, top: 382}}
                keyboardType='decimal-pad'
            />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Wrap your text and textInput in a view container

2- container style => flexDirection: row to get the text and the input in the same row

3- input has no border by default so,
set borderBottomColor & borderBottomWidth for it to get your desired style

You Can test this code on snack
https://snack.expo.dev/@salwa_soliman/input-styling

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.label}>Label Text1</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Type here"
        />
      </View>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.label}>Label Text2</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Type here"
        />
      </View>
     </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems:"center"
  },
  inputContainer:{
    flexDirection:"row",
    justifyContent:"space-between",
    alignItems:"center",
    marginVertical:10
  },
  label: {
    width:"48%",
    fontSize:20
  },
  input:{
    width:"48%",
    borderBottomColor:"#000",
    borderBottomWidth:2,
    fontSize: 20,

  }
});
```